# initializing roscore, unkown host

Tags: ros, fedora

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

OS: Fedora 14
ROS: Fuerte

Error, while initializing roscore:

> Unable to contact my own server at [http://scitos:50689/]. This usually
> means that the network is not
> configured properly.
>
> A common cause is that the machine
> cannot ping itself.  Please check for
> errors by running:
>
> ping scitos
>
> For more tips, please see
>
> http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup

ping scitos delivers

> unkown host scitos

ping localhost works fine, ping 127.0.0.1 likewise

Solutions according to [ros-wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup) is to set

> ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost
> ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

this has not worked
ping $ROS_HOSTNAME does fine,
while ping $ROS_MASTER_URI returns

> unknown host http://localhost:11311

Any ideas why this does not work? Maybe some issue concerning my network connection(using wireless for internet, still there are two ethernet accesses, which are currently not used)?

thx :-)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40140/initializing-roscore,-unkown-host/) by [Flowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/2441/flowers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 342 on 2012-07-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's clear that you can't ping the ROS_MASTER_URI. Pinging the host in the ROS_MASTER_URI is the correct way.

Could you run a roscore after setting ROS_HOSTNAME?

The other way is checking your /etc/hosts.
There should probably be a line like:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

If you add

```
127.0.0.1   scitos
```

after that, you should be able to do `ping scitos`.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0